# Issue with two local Maven projects and ${project.build.version}

Tags: maven

I have LOCAL_PROJECT_1:

```
-- multi-module-first
 |-- module-core
   |-- ...
   |-- pom.xml
 |-- module-extra
   |-- ...
   |-- pom.xml
 |-- pom.xml
```

... and LOCAL_PROJECT_2:

```
-- multi-module-second
 |-- another-module-core
   |-- ...
   |-- pom.xml
 |-- another-module-extra
   |-- ...
   |-- pom.xml
 |-- pom.xml
```

LOCAL_PROJECT_2 has a dependency of LOCAL_PROJECT_1

When I run `mvn install` on LOCAL_PROJECT_1 following directories are created in .m2/repository/PACKAGE_PATH_OF_PROJECT_1/

```
-- multi-module-first
 |-- 1 (because of <project.build.version>1</project.build.version>)
   |-- multi-module-first-1.pom
-- module-core
 |-- 1
   |-- module-core-1.jar
   |-- module-core-1.pom
-- module-extra
 |-- 1
   |-- module-extra-1.jar
   |-- module-extra-1.pom
```

Then I try to do the same with LOCAL_PROJECT_2 but I get:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project LOCAL_PROJECT_2_CORE: Could not resolve dependencies for project local.project2.groupId:another-module-core:jar:1: Failed to collect dependencies at PROJECT_1_GROUP:module-core:jar:1: Failed to read artifact descriptor for PROJECT_1_GROUP:module-core:jar:1: Could not transfer artifact PROJECT_1_GROUP:multi-module-first:pom:${project.build.version} from/to 1 (https://repo.boundlessgeo.com/main): Failed to transfer file https://repo.boundlessgeo.com/main/PACKAGE_PATH_OF_PROJECT_1/$%7Bproject.build.version%7D/PROJECT_1_GROUP-$%7Bproject.build.version%7D.pom with status code 400 -> [Help 1]
```

Main part of the error `Could not transfer artifact PROJECT_1_GROUP:multi-module-first:pom:${project.build.version}`

After this step if I inspect .m2/repository/PACKAGE_PATH_OF_PROJECT_1/ I see that directory `${project.build.version}` was created

```
-- multi-module-first
 |-- 1
   |-- multi-module-first-1.pom
 |-- ${project.build.version}
-- module-core
 |-- 1
   |-- multi-module-1.jar
   |-- multi-module-1.pom
-- module-extra
 |-- 1
   |-- multi-extra-1.jar
   |-- multi-extra-1.pom
```

and if I inspect `multi-module-first-1.pom` I see

```
...
<groupId>PROJECT_1_GROUP</groupId>
<artifactId>multi-module-first</artifactId>
<version>${project.build.version}</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<modules>
    <module>module-core</module>
    <module>module-extras</module>
</modules>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.build.version>1</project.build.version>
    <maven.compiler.source>12</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>12</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
...
```

So it looks to me that Maven does not know that it should use version `1` of the LOCAL_PROJECT_1 and thinks that version "number" it should use is equal to `${project.build.version}`.

Comment: Usage of `<version>${project.build.version}</version` in parent nor in modules makes sense nor does work that way. The question is what you like to achieve within your multi module build ? Can you elaborate more in detail?

Comment: So that there would be only one place where version for all modules (under specific parent pom) needs to be changed

Comment: Than you need the following: https://maven.apache.org/maven-ci-friendly.html but the issue is not really there cause you define the version only once manually during the initial setup of the project afterwards you only change it via maven-release-plugin or via version-maven-plugin ...never manually again...

Comment: Will look into info you have provided!